# Gradle Jacoco test coverage for integration test across sub modules

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I am having my project structure as follows,

--Project
   --Dao
   --Service
   --Controller
       --test
       --build.gradle.kts

I am having only integration tests in the controllers. All my sub modules(DAO, Services and Controllers) are gradle projects with build.gradle.kts inside them.

Following is my build.gradle.kts in my parent module, i.e. inside Project

```
import org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

val Project.`java`: JavaPluginConvention
    get() = convention.getPluginByName("java")

plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.3.61"
    val testLoggerVersion = "1.6.0"
    val dokkaVersion = "0.9.18"

    base
    jacoco
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion apply false
    maven
    id("com.adarshr.test-logger") version testLoggerVersion apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.dokka") version dokkaVersion apply false
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = jacocoVersion
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
}

allprojects {
    version = "dev"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply {
        plugin("kotlin")
        plugin("jacoco")
        plugin("com.adarshr.test-logger")
        plugin("org.jetbrains.dokka")
    }

    dependencies {
        "implementation"(kotlin("stdlib"))
        "implementation"("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinxCoroutinesVersion")

        "implementation"("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:$fasterxmlVersion")
        "implementation"("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:$fasterxmlVersion")
        "implementation"("org.koin:koin-core:$koinVersion")

        "testImplementation"("org.koin:koin-test:$koinVersion")
        "testImplementation"("io.mockk:mockk:$mockkVersion")
        "testImplementation"("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$jUnitVersion")
        "testImplementation"("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$jUnitVersion")
        "testImplementation"("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:$testcontainersVersion")
        "testImplementation"("org.testcontainers:testcontainers:$testcontainersVersion")
        "testImplementation"("org.testcontainers:postgresql:$testcontainersVersion")
        "testRuntime"("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$jUnitVersion")
    }

    tasks.register<Jar>("uberJar") {
        archiveClassifier.set("uber")
        from(java.sourceSets["main"].output)

        dependsOn(configurations["runtimeClasspath"])

        from({
            configurations["runtimeClasspath"]
                .filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }
                .map { zipTree(it) }
        })
    }

    tasks.register<Zip>("uberZip") {
        from(java.sourceSets["main"].output)

        dependsOn(configurations["runtimeClasspath"])
        from({
            configurations["runtimeClasspath"]
                .filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }
                .map { zipTree(it) }
        })
    }

    tasks.withType<DokkaTask> {
        outputFormat = "html"
        outputDirectory = "$buildDir/javadoc"
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
        targetCompatibility = javaVersion

        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = javaVersion
            apiVersion = kotlinVersion
            languageVersion = kotlinVersion
        }
    }

    tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
        reports {
            html.apply {
                isEnabled = true
                destination = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
            }
            csv.isEnabled = false
        }

        afterEvaluate {
            classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.map {
                fileTree(it).apply {
                    exclude("io/company/common/aws/test/support/**")
                    exclude("io/company/common/system/**")
                }
            }))
        }
    }

    tasks.withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
        testLogging {
            events("PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED", "STANDARD_OUT", "STANDARD_ERROR")
        }
    }


}
```

My problem is for jacoco code coverage. When I run `./gradlew clean test jacocoTestReport` I only get coverage for my controllers and not for services and daos.

My gradle version is 5.4.1.

How can I get a consolidate report for the test coverage, covering all the test modules ??
I have tried multiple links from stackoverflow, but had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [JacocoMerge](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoMerge.html) task for that, which was explicitly created for that use case. It will take the individual reports of the subprojects and merge them into one report. Add the following snippet to your root project and adjust where necessary.

```
val jacocoMerge by tasks.registering(JacocoMerge::class) {
    subprojects {
        executionData(tasks.withType<JacocoReport>().map { it.executionData })
    }
    destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco")
}

tasks.register<JacocoReport>("jacocoRootReport") {
    dependsOn(jacocoMerge)
    sourceDirectories.from(files(subprojects.map {
        it.the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"].allSource.srcDirs
    }))
    classDirectories.from(files(subprojects.map { it.the<SourceSetContainer>()["main"].output }))
    executionData(jacocoMerge.get().destinationFile)
    reports { // <- adjust
        html.isEnabled = true
        xml.isEnabled = true
        csv.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Now a `gradle jacocoRootReport` will give you the overall coverage.

Comment: Hey Arvid, I don't have any tests in DAO and Service, will this still work ? The test in the controller is invoking all these sub modules, so I need to complete coverage from my Controller's test.

Comment: If it's only about adding classes to jacoco report, you don't need new tasks but only modify the `sourceDirectories` and `classDirectories` of your existing jacoco task in the same fashion as in my snippet.

Comment: I changed the destinationFile as 
destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec")
And re ran the 'gradle jacocoRootReport' but got  > No value has been specified for property 'executionData'